# mod_rewrite in 2.4.25 triggering FCGI "Primary script unknown" error in php-fpm 5.6.30

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

- Apache: 2.4.25 (local)
- PHP-FPM: 5.6.30

This scenario fails under Apache 2.4.25 but **works under Apache 2.4.20.**

Test URL:

`https://server/some-app/fun`

And directory contents of:

```
drwxr-xr-x 118 xx root 4012 May 18 16:12 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 xx root  155 May 18 16:15 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x   1 xx root  450 May 18 16:25 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x   4 xx root  136 May 18 16:25 .
```

I expect index.php to be served up, and "/fun" to be passed as a GET parameter.

**.htaccess OK**

This version of `.htaccess` serves up index.php with no problems, and the GET parameters show "/fun" as expected:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,NS]
```

index.php is served, and $_GET is:

```
Array
(
    [/fun] => 
)
```

**.htaccess 404**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NS]
```

This one results in a 404, with PHP-FPM giving an error of:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error]  [client 192.168.200.1:59812] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
```

Notice the difference is that I removed the question mark from the RewriteRule's substitution.

**Relevant FCGI config:**

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:///var/run/php-fpm-xyz.sock|fcgi://xyz/"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Timeout 3000

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

**Sanitized Logs**

```
[ssl:info]   AH01964: Connection to child 18 established (server servername:443)
[authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(809):  AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(809):  AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] strip per-dir prefix: /data/www/some-app/fun -> fun
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'fun'
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] RewriteCond: input='fun' pattern='!^(index.php)' => matched
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] rewrite 'fun' -> 'index.php/fun'
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/fun -> /data/www/some-app/index.php/fun
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] strip document_root prefix: /data/www/some-app/index.php/fun -> /some-app/index.php/fun
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] internal redirect with /some-app/index.php/fun [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(809):  AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(809):  AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] add path info postfix: /data/www/some-app/index.php -> /data/www/some-app/index.php/fun
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] strip per-dir prefix: /data/www/some-app/index.php/fun -> index.php/fun
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/fun'
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] RewriteCond: input='index.php/fun' pattern='!^(index.php)' => not-matched
[perdir /data/www/some-app/] pass through /data/www/some-app/index.php
[proxy:debug]  mod_proxy.c(1228):  AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0)
[proxy_fcgi:debug]  mod_proxy_fcgi.c(913):  AH01076: url: fcgi://xyz//data/www/some-app/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[proxy_fcgi:debug]  mod_proxy_fcgi.c(920):  AH01078: serving URL fcgi://xyz//data/www/some-app/index.php
[proxy:debug]  proxy_util.c(2156): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[proxy:debug]  proxy_util.c(2209):  AH00944: connecting fcgi://xyz//data/www/some-app/index.php to xyz:8000
[proxy:debug]  proxy_util.c(2246):  AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /var/run/php-fpm-xyz.sock
[proxy:debug]  proxy_util.c(2418):  AH00947: connected //data/www/some-app/index.php to httpd-UDS:0
[proxy:debug]  proxy_util.c(2786): AH02823: FCGI: connection established with Unix domain socket /var/run/php-fpm-xyz.sock (*)
[authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(809):  AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(809):  AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[proxy_fcgi:error]   AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[proxy:debug]  proxy_util.c(2171): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

Comment: maybe a front double-slash is the cause, try to remove a last one from the fcgi proxy-path.

Comment: Ran into the same issue and had to downgrade Apache version. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Alexey, I did not.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue on 2.4.26 and not on 2.4.25. A `brew switch` to 2.4.25 works for me as of now, but I will look at the [changelog](http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror//httpd/CHANGES_2.4.26). 

Have you tried it on 2.4.26? Does it work?

Comment: See the explenation [here](https://serverfault.com/a/847750/240987) - it seems to a version related bug

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in this Apache version